# phonegap ios App rejected EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) crashes iPad iOs 7.1.1

Tags: xcode, ipad, cordova, ios7

I have uploaded the app and it was rejected,

"We found that your app crashed on an iPad running iOS 7.1.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app crashes upon launch."

The app was created with xCode5.1 and latest the Phonegap version. When I uploaded the app, there was no iOS 7.1.1

It seems that there is no Problem running on iPhone, I tried to reproduce the crash but no success.
I updated my iPad Device on 7.1.1 and tested again, no crashes.

> Apple's crash report
>
> ```
> Incident Identifier: A472D160-FCC9-4D93-959B-396628E53924 CrashReporter Key:   4f2c8fa05c83e9d455c232dbd2fa63e852283d0e
> ```
>
> Hardware Model:      xxx
>
> Process:             HelloWorld [9806]
>
> Path:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/DE1A86D4-A5B8-40F4-98B8-AC66E235CB5F/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
>
> Identifier:          com.development.Buch-des-Tages
>
> Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
>
> Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
>
> Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2014-04-24 13:36:17.140 -0700 OS Version:
>   iOS 7.1 (11D167) Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0057005a00240039
>
> Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:
>
> 0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00000001947c40c0 objc_retain + 32
>
> 1   HelloWorld                        0x0000000100100db0
>   -[CDVCommandQueue execute:] + 540
>
> 2   HelloWorld                        0x0000000100100acc
>   -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] + 464
>
> 3   HelloWorld                        0x00000001001007ac
>   -[CDVCommandQueue enqueCommandBatch:] + 96
>
> 4   HelloWorld                        0x00000001001008e4
>   -[CDVCommandQueue fetchCommandsFromJs] + 140
>
> 5   HelloWorld                        0x0000000100100840
>   -[CDVCommandQueue maybeFetchCommandsFromJs:] + 128
>
> 6   Foundation                        0x00000001889545c8
>   __NSThreadPerformPerform + 324
>
> 7   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000187d93040
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 20
>
> 8   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000187d9239c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 252
>
> 9   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000187d90634 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   628
>
> 10  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000187cd16cc
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
>
> 11  GraphicsServices                  0x000000018d96dc08 GSEventRunModal
>   + 164
>
> 12  UIKit                             0x000000018ae02fd8
>   UIApplicationMain + 1152
>
> 13  HelloWorld                        0x0000000100104c90 main (main.m:32)
>
> 14  libdyld.dylib                     0x0000000194d9fa9c start + 0

Comment: which cordova version you used and android version

Comment: and when you are using your apps its coming ? warning issue

Comment: Im using phonegap version 3.4.0 - 0.19.13

Comment: Im using phonegap version 3.4.0 - 0.19.13
There are some warning issues like Unused Entity Issue, Format String Issue and Desprecations. Mostly warnings depends on plugin that I used in my project. (Pushnotification, SocialSharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that Issue at

http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

hoped that solved my Rejection Problem!

Comment: The repo referred in the link is gone so can you please tell what fixed the problem?